# Converting Markdown to HTML using Go

Tags: performance, html, regex, go, markdown

I recently ported a blog of mine from Python to Go (to improve speed and performance) and while all is great so far, I'd like some help optimising the `Markdown` function to improve the general performance, maintenance and readability of the function.

I have this function because I write my blog articles in Markdown (`.md`) and then use <s>Python</s> Go to convert the raw Markdown to HTML for output as this saves me from having to write ridiculous amounts of HTML. (which can be tedious to say the least)

The `Markdown` function takes one argument (`raw`) which is a string that contains the raw Markdown (obtained using `ioutil.ReadFile`).

It then splits the Markdown by `\n` (removing the empty lines) and converts:

- Bold and italic text (***,**,*)
- Strikethrough text (~~blah blah blah~~)
- Underscored text (__blah blah blah__)
- Links ([https://example.com](Example Link))
- Blockquotes (> sample quote by an important person)
- Inline code (`abcccc`)
- Headings (h1-h6)

While some of the supported features aren't exactly standard, this function works and outputs the expected result without any errors but being a new Go programmer and this being my first *"real"* Go project I'd like to know whether or not my code could be optimised for better performance, maintainability and readability.

Here a few questions I have regarding optimisation:

- Would it make a difference to performance if I reduced the amount of imports?
- Would it improve readability if I put the `regexp.MustCompile` functions into variables above the `Markdown` function?
- Would it improve performance if I used individual regexes to convert Markdown headings instead of using `for i := 6; i >= 1; i-- {...}`?
- If not, is there a way to convert `i` (an integer) to a string without using `strconv.Itoa(i)` (to help reduce the amount of imports)?

Here is my code:

```
package parse

import (
  "regexp"
  "strings"
  "strconv"
)

func Markdown(raw string) string {
  // ignore empty lines with "string.Split(...)"
  lines := strings.FieldsFunc(raw, func(c rune) bool {
    return c == '\n'
  })
  for i, line := range lines {
    // wrap bold and italic text in "<b>" and "<i>" elements
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<b><i>$1</i></b>`)
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`\*\*(.*?)\*\*`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<b>$1</b>`)
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`\*(.*?)\*`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<i>$1</i>`)
    // wrap strikethrough text in "<s>" tags
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`\~\~(.*?)\~\~`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<s>$1</s>`)
    // wrap underscored text in "<u>" tags
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`__(.*?)__`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<u>$1</u>`)
    // convert links to anchor tags
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)[^\)]`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<a href="$2">$1</a>`)
    // escape and wrap blockquotes in "<blockquote>" tags
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`^\>(\s|)`).ReplaceAllString(line, `&gt;`)
    line = regexp.MustCompile(`\&gt\;(.*?)$`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<blockquote>$1</blockquote>`)
    // wrap the content of backticks inside of "<code>" tags
    line = regexp.MustCompile("`(.*?)`").ReplaceAllString(line, `<code>$1</code>`)
    // convert headings
    for i := 6; i >= 1; i-- {
      size, md_header := strconv.Itoa(i), strings.Repeat("#", i)
      line = regexp.MustCompile(`^` + md_header + `(\s|)(.*?)$`).ReplaceAllString(line, `<h` + size + `>$2</h` + size + `>`)
    }
    // update the line
    lines[i] = line
  }
  // return the joined lines
  return strings.Join(lines, "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Performance

#### Regex

`regex.MustCompile()` is very expensive! Do not use this method inside a loop !

instead, define your regex as global variables only once:

```
var (
    boldItalicReg = regexp.MustCompile(`\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*`)
    boldReg       = regexp.MustCompile(`\*\*(.*?)\*\*`)
    ...
)
```

#### Headers

If a line is a header, it will start by a `#`. We can check for this before calling `ReplaceAllString()` 6 times ! All we need 
 to do is to trim the line, and then check if it starts with `#`:

```
line = strings.TrimSpace(line)
if strings.HasPrefix(line, "#") {
    // convert headings
    ...
}
```

We could go further and unrolling the loop to avoid unecessary allocations:

```
count := strings.Count(line, "#")
switch count {
case 1:
    line = h1Reg.ReplaceAllString(line, `<h1>$2</h1>`)
case 2: 
    ...
}
```

#### Use a scanner

The idiomatic way to read a file line by line in go is to use a `scanner`. It takes an `io.Reader` as parameters, so you can directly pass
your mardown file instead of converting it into a string first:

```
func NewMarkdown(input io.Reader) string {


    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(input)
    for scanner.Scan() {

        line := scanner.Text()
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Use `[]byte` instead of `string`

In go, a `string` is a read-only slice of bytes. Working with strings is usually more expensive than working with slice of bytes, 
so use `[]byte` instead of `strings` when you can:

```
line := scanner.Bytes()
line = boldItalicReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<b><i>$1</i></b>`))
```

#### Write result to a `bytes.Buffer`

Instead of `string.Join()`, we can use a buffer to write each line in order to further reduce the number of allocations:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(input)
for scanner.Scan() {

    line := scanner.Bytes()
    ...
    buf.Write(line)
    buf.WriteByte('\n')
}

return buf.String()
```

final code:

```
package parse

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "regexp"
)

var (
    boldItalicReg = regexp.MustCompile(`\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*`)
    boldReg       = regexp.MustCompile(`\*\*(.*?)\*\*`)
    italicReg     = regexp.MustCompile(`\*(.*?)\*`)
    strikeReg     = regexp.MustCompile(`\~\~(.*?)\~\~`)
    underscoreReg = regexp.MustCompile(`__(.*?)__`)
    anchorReg     = regexp.MustCompile(`\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)[^\)]`)
    escapeReg     = regexp.MustCompile(`^\>(\s|)`)
    blockquoteReg = regexp.MustCompile(`\&gt\;(.*?)$`)
    backtipReg    = regexp.MustCompile("`(.*?)`")

    h1Reg = regexp.MustCompile(`^#(\s|)(.*?)$`)
    h2Reg = regexp.MustCompile(`^##(\s|)(.*?)$`)
    h3Reg = regexp.MustCompile(`^###(\s|)(.*?)$`)
    h4Reg = regexp.MustCompile(`^####(\s|)(.*?)$`)
    h5Reg = regexp.MustCompile(`^#####(\s|)(.*?)$`)
    h6Reg = regexp.MustCompile(`^######(\s|)(.*?)$`)
)

func NewMarkdown(input io.Reader) string {

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(input)
    for scanner.Scan() {

        line := bytes.TrimSpace(scanner.Bytes())
        if len(line) == 0 {
            buf.WriteByte('\n')
            continue
        }

        // wrap bold and italic text in "<b>" and "<i>" elements
        line = boldItalicReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<b><i>$1</i></b>`))
        line = boldReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<b>$1</b>`))
        line = italicReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<i>$1</i>`))
        // wrap strikethrough text in "<s>" tags
        line = strikeReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<s>$1</s>`))
        // wrap underscored text in "<u>" tags
        line = underscoreReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<u>$1</u>`))
        // convert links to anchor tags
        line = anchorReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<a href="$2">$1</a>`))
        // escape and wrap blockquotes in "<blockquote>" tags
        line = escapeReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`&gt;`))
        line = blockquoteReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<blockquote>$1</blockquote>`))
        // wrap the content of backticks inside of "<code>" tags
        line = backtipReg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<code>$1</code>`))
        // convert headings
        if line[0] == '#' {

            count := bytes.Count(line, []byte(`#`))
            switch count {
            case 1:
                line = h1Reg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<h1>$2</h1>`))
            case 2:
                line = h2Reg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<h2>$2</h2>`))
            case 3:
                line = h3Reg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<h3>$2</h3>`))
            case 4:
                line = h4Reg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<h4>$2</h4>`))
            case 5:
                line = h5Reg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<h5>$2</h5>`))
            case 6:
                line = h6Reg.ReplaceAll(line, []byte(`<h6>$2</h6>`))
            }
        }
        buf.Write(line)
        buf.WriteByte('\n')
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

### Benchmarks

I used the folowing code for benchmarks, on a 20kB md file:

```
func BenchmarkMarkdown(b *testing.B) {

    md, err := ioutil.ReadFile("README.md")
    if err != nil {
        b.Fail()
    }
    raw := string(md)
    b.ResetTimer()

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = Markdown(raw)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMarkdownNew(b *testing.B) {

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        file, err := os.Open("README.md")
        if err != nil {
            b.Fail()
        }
        _ = NewMarkdown(file)
        file.Close()
    }
}
```

Results:

```
> go test -bench=. -benchmem

goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkMarkdown-4               10     104990431 ns/op    364617427 B/op    493813 allocs/op
BenchmarkMarkdownNew-4          1000       1464745 ns/op      379376 B/op      11085 allocs/op
```

benchstat diff:

```
name        old time/op    new time/op    delta
Markdown-4     105ms ± 0%       1ms ± 0%   ~     (p=1.000 n=1+1)

name        old alloc/op   new alloc/op   delta
Markdown-4     365MB ± 0%       0MB ± 0%   ~     (p=1.000 n=1+1)

name        old allocs/op  new allocs/op  delta
Markdown-4      494k ± 0%       11k ± 0%   ~     (p=1.000 n=1+1)
```